# Follow Path & Bezier Curve not working with Lattice Modifier

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, lattice

I have an object attached to a Bezier Circle with a Follow Path Constraint. The Bezier Circle is being deformed by a Lattice Deformer. If the Lattice Modifier's 'Align on Spline' button is disabled, the Bezier Circle deforms properly, however the Follow Path Constraint doesn't work. If 'Align on Spline' is enabled, the Follow Path Constraint works, but the Bezier Circle is deforming differently.

[image: Align on Spline]

Could anyone please advise how to fix this? Here is my .blend file:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: what version r u using? in 3.1 there isn't that button...

Comment: I'm seeing it in 3.1: https://i.imgur.com/NN2CS7k.png